# Run command line after install

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I'm using the Wix Installer and after the installation is finished installing all the files, I would like the command prompt to install a service.  I'm using this element block:

```
<CustomAction Id="InstallTPG_API" Directory="TPG_API_INSTALLFOLDER" 
              ExeCommand="nssm install TPG_API &quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxpaw\TPG_Foxpaw\TPG_API\TPG_API.exe&quot;" 
              Execute="deferred" Return="ignore">
</CustomAction>
```

However, the service does not get installed.  I don't even see the command prompt window come up at all.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It worked after I made the following changes:

```
 <!-- After files are finished installing, intall and start the TPG_API service-->
<CustomAction Id="InstallTPG_API"  Directory="TPG_API_INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /c nssm install TPG_API &quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxpaw\TPG_Foxpaw\TPG_API\TPG_API.exe&quot;" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore" />
<CustomAction Id="StartTPG_API" Directory="TARGETDIR" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]cmd.exe /c net start TPG_API" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize" />
  <Custom Action="InstallTPG_API" After="InstallFinalize" />
  <Custom Action="StartTPG_API" After="InstallTPG_API" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```